# How to set a blue border to edit control?

Tags: c++, winapi, manifest

I added a manifest file to my project to set the windows XP style, it work for all controls except the edit control. I took screen shots :

My current style : [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VcU2.png)

My dream : [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VNid.png),  From Windows Notepad

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your links do not show any screen shots.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons why your edit control might not look the way you want. If you've applied a window style to the control it might override the default style. Also there are a couple of different versions of the Rich Edit control, and the older one might not be compatible; look at the window class name.

Here's a Microsoft guide to Window styles that should help you achieve the dream look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270423(v=vs.85).aspx